# Error while starting the REST connector for SNOWFLAKE

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

```
Starting the connector:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @snowflake-connector.json http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083/connectors                                                                 

post executing the above command getting error: 
{"error_code":500,"message":"Request timed out"}
```

Getting the error, as my Kafka-Zookeeper, Kafka Service and Distributed Connection Services are up and running.

Please help that how to overcome this situation

```
connect.log
[2022-05-25 22:40:17,892] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 4252 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.Distributed Herder:1208)
[2022-05-25 22:40:17,892] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.Distributed Herder:1236)
[2022-05-25 22:45:43,194] INFO JVM Runtime does not support Modules (org.eclipse.jetty.util.TypeUtil:201)
[2022-05-25 22:48:59,754] ERROR Validate: Error connecting to snowflake:
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Exception: Failed to connect to Snowflake Server
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Error Code: 1001
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Detail: Snowflake connection issue, reported by Snowflake JDBC
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Message: JWT token is invalid.
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.newSession(SessionUtil.java:614)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:284)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:435)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:104)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:164)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.java:68)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceFactory$SnowflakeConnectionServiceBuilder.build(SnowflakeConnectionServiceFactory.java:75)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector.validate(SnowflakeSinkConnector.java:234)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:375)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748), errorCode:1001 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector:236)
[2022-05-25 22:48:59,757] INFO AbstractConfig values:
 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:354)
```

Comment: `JWT token is invalid.` Here's a KB article on this: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Key-Based-Authentication-Failed-with-JWT-token-is-invalid-Error

Comment: distributed-connector-log
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1570)
May 26, 2022 12:46:06 AM net.snowflake.client.core.SFTrustManager executeOneRevocationStatusCheck
SEVERE: WARNING!!! Using fail-open to connect. Driver is connecting to an HTTPS endpoint without OCSP based Certificate Revocation checking as it could not obtain a valid OCSP Response to use from the CA OCSP responder. Details:

Comment: {"cacheEnabled":true,"ocspReqBase64":"ME8wTTBLMEkwRzAHBgUrDgMCGgQUM\/Wqxh1m5wVdAxc6TR8+GHE4hQ0EFFmkZgZSoHuVkjyjlAcnlnRb+T3QAhAHAcwqkZRE8NmS\/POgb8of","ocspMode":"FAIL_OPEN","sfcPeerHost":"xxx00000.XX-XXXX-X.snowflakecomputing.com","ocspResponderURL":"http:\/\/ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com","cacheHit":false,"eventType":"OCSPValidationError","certId":"MEcwBwYFKw4DAhoEFDP1qsYdZucFXQMXOk0fPhhxOIUNBBRZpGYGUqB7lZI8o5QHJ5Z0W\/k90AIQBwHMKpGURPDZkvzzoG\/KHw=="}
May 26, 2022 12:46:47 AM net.snowflake.client.core.SFTrustManager executeOneRevocationStatusCheck

Comment: SEVERE: WARNING!!! Using fail-open to connect. Driver is connecting to an HTTPS endpoint without OCSP based Certificate Revocation checking as it could not obtain a valid OCSP Response to use from the CA OCSP responder.Details:

Comment: {"cacheEnabled":true,"ocspReqBase64":"MEgwRjBEMEIwQDAHBgUrDgMCGgQUi8GehFuYHWHPVGkhGmi44xEzbZAEFL9ft9HO3R+G9FtVrNzXEMIOqYjnAgkApw5KTDSCt38=","ocspMode":"FAIL_OPEN","sfcPeerHost":"xxx00000.xx-xxxx-0.snowflakecomputing.com","ocspResponderURL":"http:\/\/o.ss2.us\/","cacheHit":false,"eventType":"OCSPValidationError","certId":"MEAwBwYFKw4DAhoEFIvBnoRbmB1hz1RpIRpouOMRM22QBBS\/X7fRzt0fhvRbVazc1xDCDqmI5wIJAKcOSkw0grd\/"}
[2022-05-26 00:46:47,116] ERROR Validate: Error connecting to snowflake:
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Exception: Failed to connect to Snowflake Server
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Error Code: 1001

Comment: Will this be a proper solution:                                                   https://www.snowflake.com/blog/latest-changes-to-how-snowflake-handles-ocsp/

Comment: The connector is using fail open for OCSP. That means if it cannot verify the certificate revocation, it "fails open" to assume that the certificate has not been revoked. The JWT problem is usually one of the things in the KB article. Snowflake Support can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Message: JWT token is invalid.

If you are using Key Based Authentication, please check this KB.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Key-Based-Authentication-Failed-with-JWT-token-is-invalid-Error

Comment: I updated the drivers in library          But still not able to connect with even through SNOWSQL 2022-05-27 22:25:36,906(10890/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:266  - Failed to
 validate ocsp response 254013: 254013: Response is unreliable. Its validity date is out of range:  DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  -
 Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2025-05-12 23:58:59+00:00
 DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  -
 Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2025-05-12 23:58:59+00:00

Comment: (10890/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:360  - started downloading OCSP response
cache file: http://ocsp.snowflakecomputing.com/ocsp_response_cache.json 2022-05-27 22:25:56,964
(10890/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:406  - Failed to get OCSP response cache
from http://ocsp.snowflakecomputing.com/ocsp_response_cache.json: HTTPConnectionPool
(host='ocsp.snowflakecomputing.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ocsp_response_cache.json (Caused by
ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0

Comment: I am using Apache Kafka and using private and public key based authentication with Snowflake. But as I am not able to do the connectivity with the creation of connector, so trying initially with the snowsql. upgraded the drivers even. But no success