# Snowflake Kafka connector - Request Timeout Error in Distributed mode

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, ansible-2.x

We're trying to set up an `Apache Kafka`, `Zookeeper` and `Snowflake Kafka connector` cluster on a set of 5 EC2 nodes (having Ubuntu 20.x OS) using Ansible automation scripts as below:

On node 1 and 2: Apache Kafka is setup

on node 2 and 3: Zookeeper

on node 4 and 5: Kafka-connect

While we try to bring the connector up, we face Request timeout error.

Command used to bring the Kafka-connect service up (works fine):
`sudo bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties`

Command used to bring the connector up (giving error):
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @config/snowflake-connector-config.json http://localhost:8083/connectors`

The above command gave this error:
`{"error_code":500,"message":"Request timed out"}`

What should be the ideal way to setup Kafka connect cluster?

Here is what we've tried..

While setting it up, all our services like Kafka, Zookeeper and Kafka-connect become up and running except Snowflake-Kafka connector.
The config properties related Kafka, Zookeeper and Kafka-connect are being setup correctly.
The Connector properties are also being set correctly in connect-distributed.properties for 'Distributed' mode:

1. Unique `group.id` (default value: `connect-cluster`)
2. Unique connect topics - created with replication factor of 1 (default topic names - `connect-offsets`, `connect-configs` and `connect-status`)
3. `plugin.path` (pointing to the path where Snowflake Kafka connector JAR is present)

Here is the sample `connect-distributed.properties` file we are using:

```
{
  "name":"realtime-kafka-snowflake-connector-dist",
  "config":{
  "connector.class": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "8",
  "topics": "test_topic",
  "snowflake.topic2table.map": "test_topic:test_table",
  "snowflake.url.name": "XXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
  "snowflake.user.name": "MY_USER",
  "snowflake.private.key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "snowflake.private.key.passphrase": "XXX",
  "snowflake.database.name": "XXXXXX",
  "snowflake.schema.name": "XXXXX",
  "snowflake.table.name": "test_table",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "snowflake.sink.table.name.case.sensitive": "true",
  "snowflake.sink.table.columns.inference.enabled": "true",
  "buffer.count.records": "100",
  "buffer.flush.time": "60",
  "buffer.size.bytes": "1000",
  "snowflake.connector.enable.timeouts": "false",
  "snowflake.connector.timeout": "600000",
  "errors.log.enable": "true",
  "errors.log.include.messages": "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: From the EC2 machine where Kafka Connect is hosted are you are to reach the Snowflake account hostname? Like if you do a `nslookup <account>.snowflakecomputing.com` does it resolves to a proper IP? You can also try a `curl -v https://<account>.snowflakecomputing.com`

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sergiu.
Yes, we are able to reach the SF account with both the given commands.

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72385313/error-while-starting-the-rest-connector-for-snowflake) help?

Comment: Got the issue, it was Kafka config where listeners were pointing to localhost instead of the IPs.
Although, later I encountered the error (while running Kafka connector) - "JWT token is invalid" which was due to the synchronization issue of System clock which was also resolved. Thank you!